# Delphi 10 editor change line of codes when I click on them

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I just applied a theme using Delphi IDE theme editor and now when I click on any line of code in the Delphi 10 editor the code change to another line of code, to understand what I mean see this video

https://vid.me/LfGO

Why this is happening and is there a way to fix this without uninstalling Delphi and install it again.

Update:
When I enable "highlight current line" option I dont see this problem !

Comment: If this is about @RRUZ 's IDE theme editor, I suggest you file a bug report on Git : https://github.com/RRUZ/delphi-ide-theme-editor/issues

Comment: Can you restore the original IDE without reinstalling? Or ping @RRUZ,

Comment: I think it's related to the repaining of the background (that does not have default color which is white). But even with white background this happens from time to time for me (yes, with structure highlighting turned off)

Comment: Yes I used RRUZ 's IDE theme editor but I also restored default colors but  the problem remain

Comment: That is weird,  DITE modify the syntax highlight colors only replacing some values of the Windows registry. Some questions : 1) Are you tried using another Theme?  2) If you restore the default theme and the issue still exist,  You can try disabling (or uninstalling) the third-party plugins installed like CnPack.

Comment: Hi RRUZ,
no other theme app used.  I restored the default theme but problem remain also this problem happen before installing CnPack

Comment: How you restored the default theme? Do you use the option of DITE to restore the original theme or you deleted the Windows registry entries related to the Syntax Highlight colors?

Comment: I restored default theme by using menu->set default theme values... in DITE

Comment: Ok, can you try closing the RAD Studio IDE and then delete this Windows registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\Editor\Highlight`.

Comment: @RRUZ I did that now but same problem remain.

Comment: Ok, then the issue is not related to DITE.  You must try disabling/uninstalling any third party experts. If that doesn't works you must report this to EMB.

Comment: Ok will do that  RRUZ, and thanks to everyone that try to help me.